# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows: ls command returns nothing at root level

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, windows-10

On the new Bash on Ubuntu on Windows app on Windows 10, I tried to run `ls` from the starting directory to see the subdirectories but nothing comes up. I don't really know the directory structure so I'm not sure how to proceed next. What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure this is totally noob of me but I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: ls / will list all root directories

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it probably just means the folder is empty (or only contain hidden files).
you can try `ls -a` (or `ll`) to see hidden files (including `.` and `..`) and see that it works.

you can also try to create files and folders then rerun the command to see your created files and folders.

Comment: You're right. There are just hidden folders. How do I access all of my Windows folders from Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, then?

Comment: Your C drive is at /mnt/c/

Comment: `cd ~` usually takes me to my user directory.  In bash on windows this takes me to a directory empty except for things like `.bashrc`.  It seems like there are some gotchas or caveats with mapping things.

Comment: It still takes you to your "home directory" on Windows' Bash, it's just that your home dir starts empty and it's disconnected from your Windows drive. Consider that it's like having a Linux machine with the Windows drive mounted as a secondary or network drive. But if you install Ubuntu stuff that go the "home dir" that will be where `cd ~` takes you

Comment: if you want to list all directories in root. simply type ls /

Answer (score 1):

When you see your Linux command prompt, type:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/username
```

Where `c` means C: drive and `username` is your Windows username.
Then, when you type `ls`, you will see folders like `Desktop`, `Documents`, `Downloads`, etc.